# How to access most top view controller in Xamarin iOS with Mvvmcross?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, mvvmcross

we want to find the most top ViewController in the viewstack to present a little popup.
To do this we find out the NavigationController of the key window rootviewcontroller:

```
var root = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.NavigationController;
var ctrl = rootNav.TopViewController as ViewControllerBase; // our own VC
return ctrl != null ? ctrl.Popup : null;
```

This works in debug mode - in release mode the 'RootViewController' is null?
Is MVX providing a different solution for this? How do we access to the UINavigationController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference debug-to-release suggests to me that this is a Xamarin.iOS/MonoTouch effect - possibly to do with linker settings.

It's probably worth chasing down what this issue is and trying to fix it.

However, if you do want a quick fix - if you want to instead use MvvmCross's stored reference to the RootViewController, then you can do this in a Custom Presenter which inherits from `MvxTouchViewPresenter` - see [MvxTouchViewPresenter.cs#L158](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch/Views/Presenters/MvxTouchViewPresenter.cs#L158)

Comment: Thanks Stuart for your quick fix.. I already implemented it this way and it works great. Our ViewPresenter owns now a static Property named "RootViewController" - and we've got access to it anywhere in the app :)

Answer (score 0):

This gives you top View Controller

```
 var topVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
                while (topVC.PresentedViewController != null)
                {
                    topVC = topVC.PresentedViewController;
                }
```